# Sumif with multiple criteria between variable dates

Tags: google-sheets

I need your help! I'm doing a Social media post analysis on Google sheets and trying to count the number of time each post characteristics appear for a given period of time.

Here is how my tab could look like :

```
    Column A   |   Column B   |   Column C   |           Cell : D4
      Date     |     Post     |   Language   |           01/01/2018
   01/01/2018  |    Post 1    |    French    |
   01/07/2018  |    Post 2    |    English   |           Cell : D5
   01/31/2018  |    Post 3    |    English   |           01/31/2018
   02/23/2018  |    Post 4    |    French    |
```

So for this example what would be the formula to count the number of French and English articles between selected dates (which could change) on cells D4 and D5?

Thank you for your help!

Best,

Answer (score 1):

`=COUNTIFS(C1:C5, "=French", A1:A5, ">="&D4, A1:A5, "<="&D5)`

`=COUNTIFS(C1:C5, "=English", A1:A5, ">="&D4, A1:A5, "<="&D5)`

These are samples.  You would probably want to expand the ranges to `C:C`, `A:A`, or `C2:C`, `A2:A` if there is a header row.